# Hadoop/Eclipse - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to run the PutMerge program from Hadoop in Action by Chuck Lam from Manning Publishing. It should be pretty simple, but I've had a bunch of problems trying to run it, and I've gotten to this error that I just can't figure out. Meanwhile, I'm running a basic wordcount program with no problem. I've spent about 3 days on this now. I've done all the research I possibly can on this, and I'm just lost.

Ya'll have any ideas?

Program:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;


public class PutMerge {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        FileSystem local = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);

        Path inputDir = new Path(args[0]);
        Path hdfsFile = new Path(args[1]);


        try{
            FileStatus[] inputFiles = local.listStatus(inputDir);
            FSDataOutputStream out = hdfs.create(hdfsFile);

            for (int i=0; i<=inputFiles.length; i++){
                System.out.println(inputFiles[i].getPath().getName());
                FSDataInputStream in = local.open(inputFiles[i].getPath());

                byte buffer[] = new byte[256];
                int bytesRead = 0;

                while( (bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                in.close();

            }

            out.close();

        } catch(IOException e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

Output Error from Eclipse:

```
    2015-04-09 19:45:48,321 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:413)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169)
    at PutMerge.main(PutMerge.java:16)
```

About Eclipse:

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600
```

[image: Eclipse Installation Details]

About Hadooop:

```
Hadoop 2.6.0
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r e3496499ecb8d220fba99dc5ed4c99c8f9e33bb1
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-11-13T21:10Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 18e43357c8f927c0695f1e9522859d6a
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar
```

About Java:

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

About my machine:

```
Mac OSX 10.9.5
```

Java Build Path - External JARs in Library:

[image: Hadoop Common]

Comment: Is it a maven project ?? How you are managing dependencies ? Exception is `NoClassDefFoundError`, mean dependencies are missing surely. share us dependency managing information to help you..

Comment: Did you add the `hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar` file in project library? If not, `right click the project-->properties-->Java Build Path-->Libraries-->click add External jars` and add `hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar` from `/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/` folder.

Comment: Hi @rajesh-n, Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I've added a screenshot of the external jars that I've added to the Java Build Path to the question above. As you can see, 'hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar' is in there.

Comment: Hi Mr.Chowdary, it is not a Maven project. I have Maven installed, but I haven't had to use it for the other programs I've been doing, which I've had no problems with. As for other dependencies, I have to be honest, I don't know entirely know what that means, but I haven't really done anything besides download and install hadoop, edit the necessary files to make it pseudo-distributed and try running a few programs.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with Eclipse IDE :
[image: From Package Explorer]

My basic path for ubuntu installation is usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1 (lets' say CONF)
I've added two jar files,from CONF/share/hadoop/common/lib and from CONF/share/hadoop/common.
And this is the java code (from the book Hadoop in Action) :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;


public class PutMerge {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        conf.set("fs.file.impl",org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());

        org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem hdfs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(conf);
        FileSystem local = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getLocal(conf);
        Path inputDir = new Path(args[0]);
        Path hdfsFile = new Path(args[1]);
        try {
            FileStatus[] inputFiles = local.listStatus(inputDir);
            FSDataOutputStream out = hdfs.create(hdfsFile);
            for (int i=0; i<inputFiles.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(inputFiles[i].getPath().getName());
                FSDataInputStream in = local.open(inputFiles[i].getPath());
                byte buffer[] = new byte[256];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while( (bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                in.close();
            }
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The solution for me was to export the .jar file from this code, and this what  I did :
Right click on PutMerge project, then export (from the pop-up menu) :

[image: Always from Package Explorer]

and saved the jar file in a folder named PutMerge on home/hduser directory
[image: From filesystem, PutMerge.jar]

In another folder named input (path /home/hduser/input) there are three .txt files as input for PutMerge procedure :
[image: Three input files]

And now we are ready to launch the command from a terminal session :
hadoop jar /home/hduser/PutMerge/PutMerge.jar PutMerge /home/hduser/input output4/all

and the command /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1$ hdfs dfs -cat /output4/all

will contain all the text of the three single files.

Answer (score 0):

put like this in your code

Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.set("fs.hdfs.impl",org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
            configuration.set("fs.file.impl",org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when my maven repository contained corrupted JAR files. Same as you I could see the hadoop-common-x.x.x.jar existed in eclipse when viewing the "Maven Dependencies" of my Java project. However when expanding the JAR file in eclipse and selecting the class named `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream` eclipse was reporting a message something like "Invalid LOC header".

Deleting all files from my local maven repository and executing `mvn install` again resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the configuration to run your app for debugging. Make sure you have the checkbox checked for **Include Dependencies with Provided Scope** if you have any of the dependencies and you have mentioned its scope to provided. 
It worked for me by following this approach